# Fee not bring transferred to PayPal Express on checkout

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.8

I have a site that I am building and whenever I press the "checkout with PayPal" button the shipping rates aren't being processed on PayPal. I get to the PayPal Login screen, where it shows my "Order Summary" on the left and the "Login" on the right.

Looking at the summary, the overall total doesn't add shipping - does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: is your paypal button before or after the customer enters in their address and shipping preference?

Comment: @J-Dog the paypal button is before the customer enters in their address - but the customer has to be logged into site before they can purchase anything (so we already have their info)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express checkout the buyer is redirected to a PayPal hosted page where a PayPal login option is displayed. The total on this page is a subtotal.

The customer logs in to initiate the payment and they verify their shipping address and the funding source. they are then redirected back to your cart.

It is at this point where the customer will choose their shipping option and the shipping and tax is applied. Your customer will see the final total here before they press the final "Pay" button.